# react-native-snap-carousel stack layout active different on iOS and Android

Tags: react-native, carousel, react-native-snap-carousel

I am using react-native-snap-carousel stack layout, they behavior are opposite.When view rendered , on iOS there are two items under first item; on Android, however , no item snapshot under index 0 item. Is there any property to set them behavior exactly same?
[image]

Comment: can you be more descriptive? please add some code snipped, what you've already done, so it could be easier to help you.

Comment: '<Carousel ref={(c) => { this.carousel = c; }} data={dummyData} layout={'stack'} renderItem={this.renderCell} sliderWidth={WIDTH} itemWidth={WIDTH - scaleSize(120)} activeSlideAlignment={'start'} onSnapToItem={(index)=>this.setState({activeSlide:index})}/>'